# Allocate section to fixed address in memory(flash)

Tags: c, absolute, sections

I am having a hard time getting a Section created at a fixed address so that I can place a CRC value at the top of memory. I've created a new section called `.ReservedCRC` at a fixed memory address of `0x0001 FFFC` (or at least that is what I would like to have done. But looking at the map file, the linker did not place the data in that section. Why wasn't the const array `StoredCRC` placed at fixed address `0x0001 FFFC`?

Here is what I did to fix it. Putting the `StoredCRC` array in the `ReservedCRC` section remained unchanged.

```
__attribute__( ( section(".ReservedCRC") ) )const unsigned long StoredCRC[1] 
= {0x69FB9601};
```

I added a region to the MEMORY called `CRC` at the very top of flash with a length of 4 bytes for CRC storage.

```
MEMORY
{
FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x0, LENGTH = 0x1FFFC /* 128k */
CRC (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x1FFFC, LENGTH = 4   
/*  RAM_CODE (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 0x8000     32k executable 
code area in RAM */
RAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x8000 /* 32k */
}


SECTIONS
{
(other section definitions)

/**************************************
Create new section for CRC storage
at fixed location at the top of
flash in "CRC" memory region.
**************************************/

 .ReservedCRC 0x0001FFFC:
 {  
 . = ALIGN(4); 
 KEEP(*(.ReservedCRC*))
 } > CRC 
}
```

Map File

```
.ReservedCRC    0x0001fffc        0x4
                0x0001fffc                . = ALIGN (0x4)
 *(.rodata*)
 *(.ReservedCRC*)
 .ReservedCRC   0x0001fffc        0x4 ./Source/functions.o
                0x0001fffc                StoredCRC
```